# Errno::ENOENT in Devise::RegistrationsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, devise, carrierwave

Hello. I'm trying to add an avatar to the user, but when booting I see the error below.
I use gem Carrierwave and mini_magick. Tell me how to fix this. Sorry for my english.

```
Errno::ENOENT in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
No such file or directory - identify -ping /tmp/mini_magick20120225-3898-acxvro.jpg
```

Comment: You need to install imagemagick -- what OS are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install imagemagick on your operating system.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImageMagick

You can read about what the identify command here and why is it necessary :).

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer:

I already had imagemagick installed with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). I received the same error in Production with [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/).

The `$PATH` environment variable did not include `/usr/local/bin`. So, it couldn't find the imagemagick commands.

After adding the following line to the bottom of my production environment file everything worked properly.

```
ENV['PATH'] = "/usr/local/bin:#{ENV['PATH']}"
```